# A class ouput about C++ class

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class test {
public:
    int base;
    test() {
        base = 0;
    }
};
class deri : public test {
public:
    int der;
    deri() {
        der = 1;
    }
};
void foo(test* a, size_t size) {
    for (int i = 0; i != size; i++, a++) {
        cout << (*a).base << endl;;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int main() {
//  test a[5];
    deri b[5];
//  foo(a, 5);
    foo(b, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
0
1
0
1
```

Why does the code output like in the comments?

Comment: I see you are new here in SO - that's the good and right way to send code!

Comment: I am not familiar about stackoverflow. sorry for that. I put codes as the picture.

Comment: Your implementation of `foo` assumes the `a` you're passing addresses a sequence of `test` objects, which it does *not*. The stride of a sequence of `test` is different than the stride of a sequence of `deri` due to the addition of the `deri::der` member.

Comment: It doesn't output like in the presumed output and how could it, when you're printing the same instance (a) in the loop?

Comment: @stefaanv note the increment clause of the for-loop. That `a++` isn't there by accident.

Comment: Being unfamiliar with Stack Overflow, the best thing to do would have been to read some of our existing questions to see how things are done. Rather than charging in with a bulldozer... You also should have read through the Help Centre and taken the Tour, so that you'd know what you're expected to do.

Comment: @WhozCraig: just for clarification: it wasn't in the first version of the inline code on which I commented.  It was however in the originally linked code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What foo *thinks* you're passing, an array of `test` instances:

```
      --------------------------
a --> |base|base|base|base|base|
      --------------------------
```

where each `base` is initialized to `0`.

what you're actually passing, an array of `deri` instances:

```
      ----------------------------------------------
a --> |base,der|base,der|base,der|base,der|base,der|
      ----------------------------------------------
```

where each `base` is initialized to `0`, and each `der` is initialized to `1`.

When `a` is incremented, the function increments the memory address accounting for the stride of a `test` object (since that is the type of `a`), which has but-one member: `base`. In reality, the object's being passed are `deri`, and thus have two members: `base` and `der`. Thus after the first increment, you think you're doing this:

```
      --------------------------
      |base|base|base|base|base|
      --------------------------
    a -------^
```

but in reality you're doing this:

```
      ----------------------------------------------
      |base,der|base,der|base,der|base,der|base,der|
      ----------------------------------------------
   a -------^
```

and `a`, thinking it points to the second `test`, is actually pointing to the second member of the *first* `deri` object. A little instrumentation will show this. Printing the addresses of each member before we send the array to `foo`, then showing what we're actually doing in `foo`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class test {
public:
    int base;
    test() {
        base = 0;
    }
};

class deri : public test {
public:
    int der;
    deri() {
        der = 1;
    }
};
void foo(test* a, size_t size) {
    for (int i = 0; i != size; i++, a++) {
        cout << (const void*)&(*a).base << ',' << (*a).base << endl;;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int main()
{
    deri b[5];
    for (auto const& x : b)
        std::cout <<(const void*)&x.base << ',' << (const void*)&x.der << '\n';

    foo(b, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
0x7fff5fbff970,0x7fff5fbff974
0x7fff5fbff978,0x7fff5fbff97c
0x7fff5fbff980,0x7fff5fbff984
0x7fff5fbff988,0x7fff5fbff98c
0x7fff5fbff990,0x7fff5fbff994
0x7fff5fbff970,0
0x7fff5fbff974,1
0x7fff5fbff978,0
0x7fff5fbff97c,1
0x7fff5fbff980,0
```

Note the addresses will be system-dependent but hopefully you get the idea. In short, *you have a bug*.

Comment: You are pretty friendly! Thanks for you answering question! In reality, this question is from my programming test in university.

Answer (score 1):

You iterate on "a" too (a++).
So you enter the first "a" (for instruction begin at the right, so a++ before i++) and output its base : 0
You iterate this base and display it : 1
Then you iterate an other time on "a" and display its base : 0.
And so on...

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. ~_~

Comment: What do u mean about "literate this base and display it : 1"? If I change the der to 2, then it will output 2, why is it? Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, size of deri class is twice large than size of test. I think that at 1st iteration pointer a points to the begging of object b[0] and a.base = b[0].base. However at the 2nd iteration a points to the midle of b[0] and a.base in real is b[0].der. On the 3rd iteration a points to the begging of b[1] and so on.